# Generate many random numbers

Tags: javascript, random

I need to generate 4 million unique random numbers between 1 and 1 billion of 9 digits. Fill with zeros until 9 digits.

My script works (but slow) for eq. 400000 numbers. But not for 4 millions

I need the numbers in a text file. Its fine to just CTRL+S the output.

Is there any ways to optimize the memory/performance?

```
function zeroPad(num, places) {
  var zero = places - num.toString().length + 1;
  return Array(+(zero > 0 && zero)).join("0") + num;
}
var arr = []
while (arr.length < 4000000) {
  var randomnumber = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100000000)
  if (arr.indexOf(randomnumber) > -1) continue;
  arr[arr.length] = randomnumber;
}
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  document.write(zeroPad(arr[i], 9) + '<br />');
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would someone need 4 million unique numbers?

Comment: I think this is indented incorrectly

Comment: Every time you `document.write` the browser does DOM parsing and other expensive operations. You'd be better off combining everything and adding it to the DOM once. Though with 4 million numbers, your string will become too large. Try batching it into 1000 numbers.
Though I don't think a browser can handle 4M.

Comment: The best way to improve the performance would be to _not_ do this inside a browser:  You're probably spending more time doing layout and formatting on the resulting HTML document than you're spending generating the numbers themselves.  Consider using Node.js or something else that runs at a command-line and can write the file directly.

Comment: If you need to write the numbers in a text file, why don't you just use node? Have a look at `fs.createWriteStream`:
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options
https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_streams

Answer (score 1):

You can use [generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) and [file write streams](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options) in [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/):

```
const fs = require('fs');
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('numbers.txt', {flags: 'w'});

writeStream
.on('error', error => console.log(error))
.on('close', () => console.log('done'));

const uniques = [];

function write10k() {
  let i = 0;
  while (i < 1e4) {
    const randomnumber = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 1e8);
    if (uniques.indexOf(randomnumber) > -1) continue;
    uniques[uniques.length] = randomnumber;
    const line = zeroPad(randomnumber, 9) + '\n';
    writeStream.write(line);
    i++;
  }
}

function* writeGenerator() {
  for (let i = 1; i <= 4e6; i++) {
    yield write10k();
    console.log('wrote ' + (1e3  * i));
  }
  writeStream.end();
}

function zeroPad(num, places) {
  const zero = places - num.toString().length + 1;
  return Array(+(zero > 0 && zero)).join('0') + num;
}

const iter = writeGenerator();
let next = iter.next();

while (!next.done) {
  next = iter.next();
}
```

This will create the file `numbers.txt` containing 4 million unique random numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I get a Javascript heap out of memory error. Maybe my machine is just to small for this operation

Answer (score 0):

It is a number to be printed on some packaging and printing company would have the numbers in a text file.

I ended up with just editing my code and running it 10 times with different interval.

I definitely will have a look at node.js

Thanks for your input